# Почему не работает jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Почему не работает jQuery? Должна срабатывать плавная прокрутка вверх при нажатии на кнопку, и кнопка должна быть изначально спрятана, но ничего этого нет. Кнопку постоянно видно и анимации прокрутки нет

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function (){
  $("#back-top").hide();

  $(window).scroll(function (){
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 700){
    $("#back-top").fadeIn();
   } else{
    $("#back-top").fadeOut();
   }
  });

  $("#back-top a").click(function (){
   $("body,html").animate({
    scrollTop:0
   }, 800);
   return false;
  });
 });
 
});
```

```html
<head>
 <script src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: убери обертку _$(document).ready(function(){_

Comment: @Grundy, не поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42341458/4928642 && `$(function(){$(function(){alert()})})`

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага :-)

Comment: Судя по описанию - у тебя кнопка имеет id не "back-top". добавь пример своей разметки

Comment: Кнопка: <p id="back-top"><a href="#top"><span></span>Наверх</a></p>

Comment: все работает. может просто нет скролла до нужных 700 пикселей? и лучше кнопку так сделать: <div id="back-top">Наверх</div>

Comment: Все, разобрался. Спасибо)